# Displaying form data (50 different dropdowns) in a 2x4 table

Tags: php, forms, increment

I have a form with over 50 different drop down menus. Users are only allowed to make selections from 8 out of the 50, thus my desire for the 2x4 table. Right now, I have a variable $selectCount that is set at 0. Any time a dropdown menu is selected, I add 1 (++$selectCount) to the variable. Then, I have the following code:

```
if ($selectCount = 2) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 4) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 6) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
```

For reasons unknown to me, even in instances where $selectCount's value is an odd number, the table row ends creating a 1x8 table.

Here is a larger portion of the code to better detail the problem:

```
<tr>
<?php if(!empty($_POST['one'])) {


echo "<td><img src='image folder/acct.jpg' style='display:inline; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; box-shadow:0 0 20px;'/>";
echo "<p style='color:white; margin-left: 7px; font-size: 14px;'>" . $_POST['one'] . "</p></td>";

$selectCount = ++$selectCount;

if ($selectCount = 2) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 4) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 6) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}

}

?>

<?php if(!empty($_POST['two'])) {



echo "<td><img src='image folder/alyt.jpg' style='display:inline; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; box-shadow:0 0 20px;'/>";
echo "<p style='color:white; margin-left: 7px; font-size: 14px;'>" . $_POST['two'] . "</p></td>";

$selectCount = ++$selectCount;

if ($selectCount = 2) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 4) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 6) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}

}

?>

<?php if(!empty($_POST['three'])) {


echo "<td><img src='image folder/ar.jpg' style='display:inline; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; box-shadow:0 0 20px;'/>";
echo "<p style='color:white; margin-left: 7px; font-size: 14px;'>" . $_POST['three'] . "</p></td>";

$selectCount = ++$selectCount;

if ($selectCount = 2) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 4) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 6) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}



}

?>

<?php if(!empty($_POST['four'])) {


echo "<td><img src='image folder/blgs.jpg' style='display:inline; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; box-shadow:0 0 20px;'/>";
echo "<p style='color:white; margin-left: 7px; font-size: 14px;'>" . $_POST['four'] . "</p></td>";

$selectCount = ++$selectCount;

if ($selectCount = 2) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 4) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}
if ($selectCount = 6) {
echo "</tr><tr>";}

}

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing values, but assigning them:

```
if ($selectCount = 2) {
```

should be:

```
if ($selectCount == 2) {
```

or:

```
if ($selectCount === 2) {
```

The first `if` statement assigns `2` to your variable and evaluates to `true` always.

This applies to all your comparisons.

You could also reduce the 3 `if` statements to 1:

```
if ( ($selectCount % 2) === 0 ) {
  echo "</tr><tr>";
}
```

Which basically says: If the remainder of your variable divided by `2` is `0`.